# Is there a way to change the TabLayout.Tab text color without a state list?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

The purpose of this question is to find out how to change the text color of the TabLayout.Tab, in order to set the color according to relevant data on the page.

Comment: Do you need this 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setTabTextColors(android.content.res.ColorStateList) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Design Support Library, you can use `TabLayout.SetTabTextColors(int normalColor, int selectedColor)`. ([source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setTabTextColors(int,%20int)))

This does not require a `ColorStateList` as mentioned but just two integers pointing to color resources. First parameter being the default color and the second parameter being the text color of a selected tab.

Comment: What if I want to change a particular tab but not the others?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176693/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-particular-tablayout-tab-text-color-programmatically-wi

Comment: @MichaelGabay Yes there is, please check my answer on your new question with some demo code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178482/7016022