# Is there a way to set a particular Tablayout.Tab text color programmatically, without using a state list?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

The question is how to change a single TabLayout.Tab's text color. Ideally, I'd like to iterate over the tabs and change their color based on information contained on the fragment of a corresponding ViewPager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to get the `TextView` from a specified `TabLayout.Tab` and then set the text color using `TextView.SetTextColor(Color color)`, which you can do as followed:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = new TabLayout(this);
int wantedTabIndex = 0;

TextView tabTextView = (TextView)(((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)tabLayout.GetChildAt(0)).GetChildAt(wantedTabIndex)).GetChildAt(1));

var textColor = Color.Black;
tabTextView.SetTextColor(textColor);
```

Comment: Thank you! When I originally tried this, I got confused on the casting.

Answer (score 1):

*(This is a Java answer; hopefully it is helpful despite the fact that you're using Xamarin.)*

As far as I can tell, there's no way to do this using public APIs, assuming you're working with the default view created by using a `<TabItem>` tag or by calling `setupWithViewPager(myPager)`. These ways of creating `TabLayout.Tab` instances create a package-private `TabView mView` field (which itself has a `private TextView mTextView` field). There's no way to get a reference to this `TextView`, so there's no way to do what you want.

...Unless you're willing to resort to reflection (which means this solution could break at any time). Then you could do something like this:

```
TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < tabs.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.getTabAt(i);

        Field viewField = TabLayout.Tab.class.getDeclaredField("mView");
        viewField.setAccessible(true);
        Object tabView = viewField.get(tab);

        Field textViewField = tabView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTextView");
        textViewField.setAccessible(true);
        TextView textView = (TextView) textViewField.get(tabView);

        textView.setTextColor(/* your color here */);
    }
}
catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    // TODO
}
catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but I'd like to avoid Reflection.

Comment: @MichaelGabay In that case, I think your best bet is to use `TabLayout.Tab.setCustomView()` and then you will be able to control whatever aspect of its appearance you'd like.